# Flag duplicate pairs conditionally

Tags: r, duplicates

```
id=c(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
TimeofCall=c("4:00", "13:00", "NA", "9:00", "NA", "NA")
mydata <- data.frame(id, TimeofCall)
```

I want to create a third variable that flags any duplicates that have a Time of Call in either duplicate pair as 1.

For example:

```
attempt=c("1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0")
newdata <- data.frame(id, TimeofCall, attempt)
```

Any insight into how I can create this new variable that flags duplicate pairs conditionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
within(mydata, {
  attempt <- ave(as.character(TimeofCall), id, 
                 FUN = function(x) as.numeric(as.logical(sum(x != "NA"))))
})
#   id TimeofCall attempt
# 1  2       4:00       1
# 2  2      13:00       1
# 3  3         NA       1
# 4  3       9:00       1
# 5  4         NA       0
# 6  4         NA       0
```

---

With `data.table`, this is even more compact:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydata)
DT[, attempt := as.numeric(as.logical(sum(TimeofCall != "NA"))), by = id]
DT
#    id TimeofCall attempt
# 1:  2       4:00       1
# 2:  2      13:00       1
# 3:  3         NA       1
# 4:  3       9:00       1
# 5:  4         NA       0
# 6:  4         NA       0
```

---

Note that I've taken this approach because your "NA" values in your "TimeofCall" column are actually character strings, not `NA`. You can use slightly different approaches if they were actual `NA` values.

Comment: Re: your first solution--> What if I wanted to check for duplicates based on two variables? That is ID and Type, for example. Is this possible?

Comment: @Tan, Do you mean two or more "grouping" variables? Then yes, no problem. Just use a construct like `ave(as.character(TimeofCall), groupingVariable1, groupingVariable2, ...` and so on.